# Displaying XML String with Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, web

I am trying to render an XML document to the browser, but I am getting a blank screen. However, when I view the source of the page I can see the XML.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "view-xml", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public ResponseEntity<String> viewXmlPayload(@RequestParam ("id") int taskId){

    payload = dao.getXmlPayload(taskId);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(payload, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Using some browsers tools I can see that the content-type is set correctly to "text/xml", but I am still not seeing anything on the page.

Comment: you mean the response is blank (even when you view source)?

Comment: @Manish the page displays nothing, but when I view the source I can see the XML.

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC 3023](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023.txt)

```
If an XML document -- that is, the unprocessed, source XML document -- is readable by
casual users, text/xml is preferable to application/xml. MIME user agents (and web user
agents) that do not have explicit support for text/xml will treat it as text/plain, for 
example, by displaying the XML MIME entity as plain text. Application/xml is preferable when the XML MIME entity is unreadable by casual users.
```

It may not be a problem with  your code, some `browser` do not render XML at all. Instead of `text/xml`,  you need to use `application/xml`

Why you are trying to render XML document to the browser, if you still want to render, use `XSLT`to transform the `XML` into `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use XML Marshaller http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html
or manually you use common libs like this :

```
    @RequestMapping("/downloadXML.do")
public ModelAndView downloadXML(HttpServletResponse  response,@RequestParam("xmlName") String xmlName ) {   

String doc=serviceXml.getXml(xmlName);      

    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" +doc.getFilename()+ "\"");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType(doc.getContentType());
        in = doc.getInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two items:

1. Set the content type to "text/xml". You can do it either in the controller request handler method --> `response.setContentType("text/xml");`or if your xml content is in a separate JSP file, set the `<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>` directive at the top.
2. Make sure in applicationContext.xml, following property is added in the viewResolver bean configuration.
   `<property name="alwaysInclude" value="true" />`.